# NHibernate Envers - error at many-to-many relationship with the same type

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

I'm totally new to NHibernate Envers, I have added new field to the entity mapping many-to-many relationship.

```
public class Product 
{
// initialization in ctor
...
public virtual ISet<FundProduct> ExcludedFromConversion { get; set; }
...
// mapping in ClassMap
            Set(x => x.ExcludedFromConversion, m =>
            {
                m.Table("ExcludedProduct");
                m.Cascade(Cascade.None);
                m.Key(k => k.Column("ProdId"));
            }, map => map.ManyToMany(p => p.Column("ExcludedProdId")))
...
}
```

and this line in Envers configuration keep throwing an exception:

```
protected virtual void ConfigureEnvers() 
{
...       
configuration.IntegrateWithEnvers(enversConf);
}
```

Message "Cannot cast 'NHibernate.Mapping.Formula' to 'NHibernate.Mapping.Column'."
and top of the stack trace: in "   w NHibernate.Envers.Tools.MappingTools.b__0(ISelectable f)  in System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() (...)

I have tried to disable the auditing for this propety by adding `[NotAudited]` and `[Audited(TargetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NotAudited)]` but it didn't help.

It works without Envers (with the ConfigureEnvers method disabled).

Any help/ideas are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [this](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHE-135) issue. It has been fixed in latest envers version (2.0 CR1 - it has just been released). What version are you using?

Comment: This project is using 1.6.0.

Comment: You can try to manually build latest envers code from its 1.x branch.

Comment: Try to, as a test, to remove your formula mapping from the entites in your many-to-many mapping.

Comment: Thanks for another answer. But could you tell, which one is formula mapping?

Comment: Thanks, man!
Indeed, I commented out formula mapping and it suddenly compiles :). But those formulas are rather useful so I can't leave it like this. So I suppose my options are: 1. update NH/Envers 2. get rid of the formula mapping?

Comment: yes. or 3. Compile latest envers code on its 1.x branch.